# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'id_cita' in 'field list'

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, web-applications

I am trying to show the database table information, but I am getting this error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'id_cita' in 'field list'

This is the code that I am using:

```
SELECT id_cita, paciente, dia_fecha, mes_fecha, anio_fecha, hora, minutos,am_pm FROM citas ORDER BY id_cita
```

This is the database table citas:

[image: Database table citas]

This image show that the column "id_cita"  exist.

I have searched a answer, but what I have got, is too specific for each case.

Well, I do not know where is the error.

Answer (score 2):

If you look closely, column names in `cita` table do not have **underscores**, but **spaces** in their names. So it is not `id_cita`, it is `id cita`

To fix it, you need to quote the field name on your query, like this

```
SELECT 'id cita' FROM citas ORDER BY 'id cita'
```

You have to apply this to all other fields that have spaces on their names

Comment: It something strange :-( because I saw this detail,but if I put the pointer over the column the name "id_cita" appears. 

[error1]

I decided to take your advice. I remade the table without underscores in the columns names. 

[error3]

But I am having the same error.

[error2]

[error1]: http://i288.photobucket.com/albums/ll178/Marvin_Cerdas/error1_zpslcy7bshu.png

[error2]: http://i288.photobucket.com/albums/ll178/Marvin_Cerdas/error2_zpsub69on5t.png

[error3]: http://i288.photobucket.com/albums/ll178/Marvin_Cerdas/error3_zps4l02dijz.png

Comment: It something strange :-( because I saw this detail,but if I put the pointer over the column the name "id_cita" appears. 

[error1] http://i288.photobucket.com/albums/ll178/Marvin_Cerdas/error1_zpslcy7bshu.png

I decided to take your advice. I remade the table without underscores in the columns names. 

[error3]: http://i288.photobucket.com/albums/ll178/Marvin_Cerdas/error3_zps4l02dijz.png

But I am having the same error.

[error2]: http://i288.photobucket.com/albums/ll178/Marvin_Cerdas/error2_zpsub69on5t.png

Comment: I think you mean \`id cita\` (for MySQL) or "id cita" (for SQL standard compliant databases) instead of 'id cita' (which is a string literal).